# Wireless adapter won't enable

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, 64-bit

I bought a d-link dwa-125, plugged it in and windows recognized it right away and said everything was good to go.  But there were no connection options.  When I open up the network control panel and have it show me the adapters... the wireless adapter is greyed out and says it is disabled.  So I tell it to enable.  It says is it enabling, then says it is enabled... but the adapter stayed greyed out saying disabled.  I am running 7 x64.

I have reinstalled drivers, connected it via lan and had it update drivers.. same problem.
It works just fine on any other computer in the house, just not this one.

Answer (score 1):

From what you are saying, it reminds me of what happens when the Wireless service is set to disabled. To check and enable it:

Click the `Start Orb` and Right click on `Computer`, then click `Manage`.

Go down to `Services and Applications` > `Services`.

Make sure that the service `WLAN AutoConfig` is set to `Started / Automatic`

Please let me know if this helped you or if the problem is something else.

Comment: It is set to automatic, and it says it is started